# Find the Most recent record in the table without duplicate

Tags: mysql

I am trying to access the most recent message but when I join the table all the duplicate are also there and when I try to use `GROUP BY` duplicate will be gone, but result are not the most recent row to how to fix it

When I am using this query:

```
SELECT messages.id,messages.message, account.id , account.name 
FROM account 
INNER JOIN messages ON account.id = messages.sender_id WHERE receiver_id = 89 
ORDER BY messageS.date DESC, messages.time DESC;
```

[image]

duplicate result are found like you can see in this image; *anil* and *rahul* are duplicate.

When I am using this query:

```
SELECT messages.id,messages.message, account.id, account.name
FROM account INNER JOIN messages ON account.id = messages.sender_id
WHERE receiver_id = 89
GROUP BY account.id ORDER BY messages.date DESC, messages.time DESC;
```

[image]

duplicate record are fixed, but most recent message is also gone, like "Hey Bro" and "Tell Me" that are the most recent message by two different persons.

So, how can we fetch the message without duplicate and most recent messages?

Account Table
[image]

Messages Table
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to include *account* and *messages* table?

Comment: Updated Successfully you can check it now

Comment: @VishalKumar Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```sql
SELECT M.id, M.message, A.id, A.name
FROM account A INNER JOIN messages M ON A.id = M.sender_id
WHERE A.receiver_id = 89 AND M.id IN ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages GROUP BY sender_id) ORDER BY M.id;
```

Comment: Thanks You its working but you miss in the query instead of A.receiver_id it is M.receiver_id  after WHERE clause but Thanks You so much its properly working you are a genius